# Insert variable value inside shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use the shortcode below to add a review box to posts in my wordpress template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[rwp-review id="X"]'); ?>
```

Where X is the Review ID of the review box for each post.

To get the Review ID, I have the code below but it is not working. `$postid` gets the current post ID. `$box` result returns array values for the review box one of which is the Review ID. If I echo `$reviewid`, I get the Review ID which can be 0, 1, 2, 3 and upwards.
I then tried to use `$reviewid` in the final shortcode but It is not working. I have very little PHP knowledge so I think I inserted the code the wrong way.

```
<?php
        $postid = get_the_ID();
        $box = RWP_API::get_post_reviews_boxes( $postid, false );
        $reviewid = $box[0]['review_id'];

    ?>

    <?php echo do_shortcode('[rwp-review id=". $reviewid . "]'); ?>
```

Can anyone suggest the best approach to this?

Comment: Where are you putting your code that starts with $postid = get_the_ID()? You may need to add global $post; depending on where it is, and if it's hooked up to an action or not.

Comment: This code is inside the content-single.php file which is part of the single.php. There is global $post somewhere at the top of the file too. When I echo $postid, it gave me the correct post id value. Same thing when I echo $reviewid, I got the correct review ID too. I think the challenge is getting the value I got for review ID to be recognized as X in the shortcode

Comment: Seems like an issue with the plugin, found something similar here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200402/review-plugin-configuration - not sure what the API looks like, it's a paid plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[rwp-review id="'. $reviewid . '"]'); ?>`

or

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[rwp-review id='{$reviewid}']"); ?>`

Comment: Both of these code worked. I opted for the first one. Thanks.

Comment: Good on ya Leekie. The $reviewid var wasn't being parsed, the shortcode was literally looking for `. $reviewid . `